# Banner javascript becomes more faster

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code attached below , I'm trying to make a banner with javascript.

With setInterval I do a cycle which shows me 3 divs, one after another .

The problem I have is that when the cycle ends , there is a button that says "back ", that is to cycle banner again to run , but the run me faster, I do not know why this happens as this in 1 second ( 1000) , and every time I click the button the speed is increased .

Why does this happen?

Any ideas ?

Thank you so much

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var i = 0;
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(Ver,1000);
$( document ).ready(function() {

refreshIntervalId;

});


function Ver(){

    if ( i == 0 ){

        $("#div1").css("display","block");
        $("#div2").css("display","none");
        $("#div3").css("display","none");   

    }

    if ( i == 1 ){

        $("#div2").css("display","block");
        $("#div1").css("display","none");
        $("#div3").css("display","none");   

    }

    if ( i == 2 ){

        $("#div3").css("display","block");
        $("#div2").css("display","none");
        $("#div1").css("display","none");
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);       

    }

    i++;
}

function Volver(){
    i = 0;
    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(Ver,1000);  
}


</script>


<div id="div1" style="background:#F00;width:300px;height:300px;display:none">


</div>


<div id="div2" style="background:#00F;width:300px;height:300px;display:none">


</div>


<div id="div3" style="background:#0FF;width:300px;height:300px;display:none">

<input type="button" value="volver" onclick="Volver()" />
</div>
```

Comment: `var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(Ver,1000);` already starts the interval. `$( document ).ready(function() {refreshIntervalId;});` does nothing.

Comment: So much code that could be written with so many fewer lines `function Ver(){
    $("#div" + (i+1)).show().siblings().hide();
    i++;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tqqLpf0n/2/)**

You're not clearing the first interval that you create, so more than one is running at the same time

```
function Volver(){
    i = 0;
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(Ver,1000);  
}
```

Also you have a lot of code that is not necessary. See below.

```
<input type="button" value="volver" /> <!-- remove the onclick - you're using jQuery -->
```

JS

```
var i = 0;
var refreshIntervalId; // don't start the interval here- reuse the function you created
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Since you want this button to do the same thing anyway,
    // bind this event and trigger it rather then execute the function separately
    $('input').on('click', Volver).trigger('click');
});

function Ver(){
    // show programatically, and hide by using .siblings() rather than
    // writing out many lines
    $("#div" + (i+1)).show().siblings().hide();

    i++;
    // self-clear after 3 iterations as there are no more divs 
    if (i>2) clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
}

function Volver(){
    i = 0;
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(Ver,1000);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting a new interval with every click. You need to `clearInterval()` before setting a new one. Note that `var refreshIntervalId` is not the same as the global `refreshIntervalId` as it's a completely different local variable with the same name (*meaning that it's never cleared*):

```
function Volver(){
    i = 0;
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId); 
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(Ver,1000);  
}
```